# How do I close the console in OpenTTD?

Tags: openttd

Sometimes I accidentally press `^` to open the console in OpenTTD. How do I close it again? Pressing `^` again does nothing. Commands `quit` and `exit` close the game. `list_cmds` doesn't list any command for closing the console. Pressing various other keys doesn't seem to help either.

I'm on a German keyboard if this matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [OpenTTD wiki](https://wiki.openttd.org/en/Manual/Console), there is a "Toggle Console" option in the help menu.

Comment: Indeed, there is and it works!
Meanwhile I tested with an English keyboard layout and here the same key that opens the console (\`) also closes it. With a German keyboard layout this doesn't work, however.

Comment: @scai on other keyboards shoud be '~'